# FindBugs - Redundant Comparison to null

Tags: java, code-analysis, findbugs

I am having findbugs error for the below code,

```
if( obj instanceof CustomerData )
{
    CustomerData customerData = (CustomerData)obj;

    if (customerData == null) 
    {
        errors.reject("Error", "Null data received");
    }
}
```

**Error Desc:**

Redundant nullcheck of obj, which is known to be non-null in (Package and Method name, I have removed due to security violation)

This method contains a redundant check of a known non-null value against the constant null.

Please let me know what is the error in here.

Comment: From the error, I would assume that `CustomerData customerData = (CustomerData)obj;` would throw an exception if `obj` was null, therefor this `if (customerData == null)` is redundant (or, the code above makes it clear that `obj` is `not null`).

Comment: I have added "if condition" code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`instanceof` returns false if the argument is `null`. So you don't need another check.

Answer (score 4):

I've added comments inline below...

According to [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm), `instanceof` returns `false`, for a `null` instance.

```
if( obj instanceof CustomerData )
{

    /* To get here, obj must be a non-null instance of CustomerData,
     * so the following cast will always succeed and result in a non-null
     * customerData
     */

    CustomerData customerData = (CustomerData)obj;

    /* customerData cannot be null because of the conditions above, so
     * this check is pointless (it'll never be triggered
     */

    if (customerData == null) 
    {
        /* This line cannot be reached, because of the conditions above */
        errors.reject("Error", "Null data received");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `obj` cannot be null in the context of that particular check. Findbugs can tell, and warns you to remove the redudant check. Unless you provide us with the source code where `obj` is declared/defined we cannot help you more.

That said, Findbugs errors/warnings are not necessarily a problem. In this case, for example, if you feel that the check may be necessary in the future, you may just ignore the warning. A common case would be during testing where you hardcode input objects to test a specific code path, but you still need the null-check in production for safety.

EDIT (Following the question edit):

Well, `null instanceof <Whatever>` is always false, so the `instanceof` conditional in your code ensures that `obj` cannot be null. In this case you will probably want to remove the null-check - it's superfluous and Findbugs did well to point it out...